# Curve fit error: "Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated" to logistic model

Tags: python, logistic-regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to use `curve_fit` to fit the following data to a logistic function, as seen bellow. My code for this is very simple:

```
X=[0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180]
Y=[0.037812, 0.037735, 0.037721, 0.037634, 0.037373, 0.037173, 0.036373, 0.035833, 0.035741, 0.035727, 0.035668, 0.035674, 0.035652]

def logistic(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a / (1.0 + np.exp(-c * (x - d))) + b

popt, pcov = fit(logistic, X, Y)

plt.plot(X,Y, 'o',label='Data')
lin=np.linspace(0,180,1000)
plt.plot(lin,logistic(lin,*pop), '--')
```

But when I run it I get this error:

> OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated

and the plotted curve looks nothing like it should. Can anyone see why Python can't fit my data to a logistic curve?
[image: LogFit]

Comment: You define X and Y but you are plotting X and T, perhaps that could explain why they do not look alike. It would help more if you posted your full example.

Comment: that was just a typo when transcribing the code, I was plotting X, Y though

Answer (score 1):

If your fit is bad, the most common fix is to specify reasonable starting points for the optimization via the `p0` parameter (which defaults to all ones): https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html.
The fit in your picture actually looks like a local minimum (quickly become constant equal to the average value of the data), so better initial guesses for the parameters will probably help.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as fit


def logistic(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a / (1.0 + np.exp(-c * (x - d))) + b


def main():
    X = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180]
    Y = [0.037812, 0.037735, 0.037721, 0.037634, 0.037373, 0.037173, 0.036373, 0.035833, 0.035741, 0.035727, 0.035668, 0.035674, 0.035652]

    p0 = (1., 1., 1./100, 75.)
    popt, pcov = fit(logistic, X, Y, p0=p0)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', label='Data')
    lin = np.linspace(0, 180, 1000)
    plt.plot(lin, logistic(lin, *popt), '--')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Indeed, here's the fit I got just by changing the `p0` parameter:

[image: logistic fit]